# Angular Translate - FallbackLanguage with StaticFilesLoader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

So I am using Angular Translate v2.0.0 in my projects and I have three language files created: "en.json", "en-US.json", and "en-EU.json" that are loaded via the StaticFilesLoader. What I want to happen is when the key doesn't exist inside one of the "en-*" files to look for it inside the "en.json" file. Is this possible? It works when I define my translations via the $translateProvider.translations(), but I need to load the static files.

Here is my code:

/i18n/en.json

```
{ "sidebar": { "HEADING": "I AM HEADING" }}
```

/i18n/en-US.json

```
{ "formats": { "date": "MM/DD/YYYY" }}
```

/i18n/en-EU.json

```
{ "formats": { "date": "DD/MM/YYYY" }}
```

Then, inside my configuration I have:

```
 // Register a loader for the static files
// So, the module will search missing translation tables under the specified urls.
// Those urls are [prefix][langKey][suffix].
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'i18n/',
    suffix: '.json'
});

// Tell the module what language to use by default
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en-US');

// Set the fallback language to use if the string cannot be found in the default locale
$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');

// Tell the module to store the language in the cookies
$translateProvider.useCookieStorage();

// For security, we set the sanitize strategy to make sure our strings are sanitized correctly
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');

// For debugging missing translations, uncomment to use
$translateProvider.useMissingTranslationHandlerLog();
```

But when loading up the application, only the "formats.date" render and it is saying that the "sidebar.HEADING" does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it is not possible to do what I want to do without a CustomLoader or something. I just started using https://github.com/RobbinHabermehl/gulp-angular-translate and added it to a part of my build step. It is better anyway because the language will be loaded right away rather than async.